# Download only man pages / all man pages

Tags: man

Frequently I'll be in a situation where I want to read the man page for some software, even though I don't have it installed.

Specifically this time I want the `syslogd` man page, but I use Arch Linux with `systemd` (which replaces `syslogd`). And if you've ben following Arch recently, you'd know that Arch doesn't even support `syslogd` anymore (in favor of `systemd`), so the usual approach of "download the entire software just to get the `man` page" won't work here.

So, is there a resource for downloading just man pages, or even downloading all man pages (similar to how some websites host man pages in HTML)?

Comment: What's wrong with just Googling as-needed?

Comment: 1. I'd prefer to use a terminal.
2. My less is configured nicely.
3. I don't want to waste time Googling.

Comment: Define "all" manpages. Then iterate over multiple variants and versions that might be in use for any given program...

Comment: Whatever system man page hosting websites use would be acceptable.

Comment: systemd replaces init, not syslogd.

Comment: @Frank The answer to your question is http://www.google.com (search for "man <program>" or "<program> man page", optionally also listing the OS you care about).  Beyond that, [Server Fault doesn't really do "list-of-links" answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231)...

Comment: @MichaelHampton Actually, systemd now has its own journal system integrated into systemd that replaces syslogd.

Comment: @voretaq7 I don't want a list of links, because that wouldn't be any better than Googling. I want a method to download every man page locally, without the hassle.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to have it in a terminal why not just use `elinks`. I typically use the website: http://linux.die.net for looking up man pages.

You could set a bash function up like so:

```
function myman() { elinks http://linux.die.net/man/ ;}
```

You run it like so:

```
myman
```

#### Screenshots

[image: ss #1]

[image: ss #2]

[image: ss #3]

Comment: Nice trick. Also if you prefer w3m: `function myman() { w3m http://linux.die.net/man/ ;}`. Anyways, very clever.